# VBA Excel - Mail Merge to PDF Looping through datasets

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, pdf, mailmerge

Here is the scenario.  I am using VBA in Excel 2016 to initiate a mail merge with Word.  The data source for the merge is a spreadsheet in the current Excel document.  The routine generates a separate merge document for each iteration of a dataset.

As I loop through the datasets, a new merge doc is created and saved as a PDF document.

Issue #1:

The routine as it loops creates the separate merge docs.  Each merge doc is visible, so if I loop through 5 datasets, I get 5 open merge docs, each with the appropriate dataset values.  But when saving as PDF, it saves the first merge doc over and over again.

In my code, the "Save As PDF" section generates a unique filename based on a field from the dataset and that works.  Each saved PDF has the appropriate filename, but the actual file is the first merge doc over and over again.

How can I get the routine to save the first merge doc as PDF and then move on to the next iteration?

Issue #2:

As the routine loops and creates the independent merge docs, how can I then close the newly created word merge docs?

Existing code:

```
z = 0
For z = 0 To xCount - 1

lb2_selected = "''" + lb2_array(0, z) + "''"

addr_query = "sp_address_filter '" + lb2_selected + "','" + lb1_selected + "','','" + lb3_selected + "','',''"
'MsgBox (addr_query)

Set rs = conn.Execute(addr_query)

'Clear any existing data from Sheet2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z10000").Clear

'Load new iteration of data into Sheet2
With rs
    For h = 1 To .Fields.Count
        Sheet2.Cells(1, h) = .Fields(h - 1).Name
        Sheet2.Cells(1, h).Font.Bold = True

    Next h
End With

If Not rs.EOF Then
Sheets(2).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
rs.Close

'Set value for filename
lb2_array_value = lb2_array(1, z)


Dim wd As Object
Dim wdocSource As Object

Dim strWorkbookName As String

Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("c:\users\john\documents\LabelPage3.docx")

    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"

    With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "C:\users\john\documents\labels\" + lb2_array_value + ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

    wd.Visible = True

    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

Next z
```

Comment: For Issue #2, the document close and release of objects at end does not close document?

Comment: Correct.  The resulting merge docs (one per iteration of the loop) remain open.

Comment: Odd.  My posts and Parfait posts from today are gone.  That blows.  :(

Comment: Not all is lost however.  After some tinkering, I found that by modifying:

    "ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat..."

To

    "wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat..."

This results in each iteration of the loop creating a separate PDF of the merged document.

Comment: Ahhh....  That explains it.  Thanks for letting me know.  

The data source is updating as it loops.  See my previous post as I believe I have it working.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues emerge with your current setup. Consider the following adjustments:

1. **MS WORD OBJECT**: `ActiveDocument` is part of the MS Word object library and not Excel. By not qualifying it with a Word.Application object, you are assuming it for Excel. Therefore, qualify it accordingly: `wd.ActiveDocument`. On my end, doing this hangs Excel infinitely without error.
2. **EARLY BINDING** Since none of your Word constants are declared, you seem to have a VBA reference to MS Word Object Library checked off. Therefore, do not mix late-binded with early binding calls:

   Change the following:

   ```
   Dim wd As Object
   Dim wdocSource As Object

   ...

   Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   ```

   To the below:

   ```
   Dim wd As Word.Application
   Dim wdocSource As Word.Document

   ...

   Set wd = New Word.Application
   ```
3. **LOOP PROCESS**: Place your Word object assignment outside of the loop as only the documents need to be set and unset inside the loop. And use the [Application.Quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/application-quit-method-word) method to effectively close out the object.

   ```
   Dim wd As Word.Application
   Dim wdocSource As Word.Document

   ...

   Set wd = New Word.Application
   wd.Visible = True

   For z = 0 To xCount - 1
        ... ' SHEET QUERY PROCESS

        Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("c:\users\john\documents\LabelPage3.docx")

        ... ' MAIL MERGE PROCESS

        wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set wdocSource = Nothing
   Next z

   wd.Quit False
   Set wd = Nothing
   ```
4. **WITH BLOCK**: For easy readability, consistently use the `With...End With` block for `MailMerge` process:

   ```
   With wdocSource.MailMerge
       .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

       .OpenDataSource _
           Name:=strWorkbookName, _
           AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
           Revert:=False, _
           Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
           Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
           SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"

       .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
       .SuppressBlankLines = True
       With .DataSource
           .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
           .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
       End With
       .Execute Pause:=False
   End With
   ```
5. **ERROR HANDLING**: As best practice, wrap entire process in error handling especially to destroy objects as code resulting in runtime error will leave object running as a background process.

   ```
   Public Sub RunMailMerge()
   On Error GoTo ErrHandle

       ...       

   ExitHandle:
       wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
       Set wdocSource = Nothing

       wd.Quit False
       Set wd = Nothing
       Exit Sub

   ErrHandle:
       MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
       Resume ExitHandle    
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  However, making the change as indicated results in the "Source" doc (merge template) being saved as PDF after each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the loop. You should use indentation in code for readability. However, what is the desired result if you do not want each *Source* mail merged document exported as PDF? I am assuming the *xCount* of loop is the 5 datasets? So are you getting 5 PDFs?

Comment: Hi.  Sorry about the formatting.  You are correct in that "xCount" represents the number of different datasets that will be retrieved to become the datasource for the merge.  Currently, I am just putting the resulting dataset contents into 'Sheet2' each time through the loop.

The desired result is to have each iteration through the loop to generate the appropriate merge doc and save it as a PDF.

The current code does generate the appropriate merge docs, but it does not save them separately as PDF. It just keeps saving the initially generated merge doc with different filename as it loops.

Comment: The revision you suggested appears to refer to the mailmerge "Source" document and not the resulting merged documents.  So, the result is that the merge template doc ends up being saved as the PDF.

Comment: Either save just before exporting OR activate the document just after opening. See my extended answer.

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to referring to "wdocSource" object.  From what I can tell, "wdocSource" always refers to the initial mail merge source document named "LabelPage3.docx".

If I reference "wdocSource" object, all I get is "LabelPage3.docx".  Not the resulting merged document.

Comment: Parfait, you are a Rockstar.  Thanks for laying all that out for me.  I'm going to go through and clean up the code as you outlined.  This is exactly what I needed get a better understanding of the "Best Practices" and logical flow of what I am trying to accomplish.  Coding is not my primary job and I tend to scavenge for existing code snippets to get what I need.  Thanks for making yourself available to help out those of us like me who clearly need the help.